# Complex number summation

Tags: complex-numbers

For $\alpha=\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})+i \sin(\frac{2\pi}{7})$,  we have $$\left|\sum_{r=0}^{3n-1}  (\alpha^{2^{r}})\right|^2=32.$$ Find the value of $n$.

Comment: This is a complex type question not able to proceed

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler's formula? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is $r$ here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\alpha=\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}=e^{2\pi i/7}$, therefore
$$\alpha^{2^r}=e^{2^{r+1}\pi i/7}$$
Note that modulo 7
$$2^{r+1}\equiv \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } r=3k-1 \\ 2 &\text{if } r=3k\\4& \text{if }r=3k+1\end{cases}$$
which implies
$$e^{2^{r+1}\pi i/7}\equiv \begin{cases} e^{\pi i/7} & \text{if }r=3k-1 \\ e^{2\pi i/7} & \text{if }r=3k\\e^{4\pi i/7}&\text{if } r=3k+1\end{cases}$$
can you continue?